# How can I set background-img in react css?

Tags: reactjs, image, postcss

[image]

this is how my directory looks like.

I've tried many ways like

```css
background-image: url("./pencil/pencil.png");

background-image: url("./img/pencil/pencil.png");

background-image: url("/pencil/pencil.png");

background-image: url("/img/pencil/pencil.png");
```

but all these showed Can't resolve error.
I'm using PostCSS!
how can I bring images in the css? 
(In jsx file I could bring this way
src={window.location.origin + '/img/pencil/pencil.png'})

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your images in the /src directory otherwise it won't work.

Comment: so it works when I use image on jsx but it won't work on css file? omg..